# UTM zone not shown in CRS drop down menu

Tags: qgis

I try to accomplish Lesson 6.2 in "Training Manual". I use Version 6.28 of QGIS. In paragraph "6.2.5. Try Yourself Convert Layers’ CRS" it is suggested "Change the CRS to WGS 84 / UTM zone 34S". But in a dialog "Save vector layers as.." in drop down CRS there is no UTM option. So how this problem could be resolved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the dropdown which only lists recently used CRS, use the Select CRS button

[image]

[image]